# What's the the learning-resources tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just spotted this question...

[What are some good, free resources to teach myself to play piano?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/69231/what-are-some-good-free-resources-to-teach-myself-to-play-piano)

..and its use of the [learning-resources](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-resources) tag.

This tag doesn't have any usage guidance, but given that requesting external resources is off-topic, I'm struggling to think what use the tag has.

Comment: I can't think of any use either - the 36 questions on this tag don't need it, in my opinion. Let's see if anyone has any good suggestions :-)

Comment: At a stretch, I can see an argument for using it to ask for clarification on a quote or piece of music from a learning resource (something like "I have been using _x_ to learn piano, but I don't understand what they mean by _y_..."). That is a _large_ stretch though, and I'm not certain that the tag is necessary even there as there is already a `learning` tag which seems to cover that. It seems to suggest that questions asking about finding new learning resources are not off-topic (to me at least)... I am interested if there are any potential alternative uses for it though :)